# Prove By Induction $1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/(2^n) ≥ 1 + n/2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

$1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/(2^n) ≥ 1 + n/2$

I'm trying to prove by induction. But i can't really figure out the basis step. if $n = 1$ what would the inequality simplify into? $1 ≥ 1 + 1/2$? I can't really figure out the pattern here.

Comment: The sum goes up to $1/2^n$, so for $n=1$ you get $1+1/2^1$. To clarify further, for $n=2$ you get $1+1/2+1/3+1/4$, as $1/4=1/2^2$.

Comment: The punchline is that $(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8})>(\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8})=\frac{1}{2}$.  In the same way, the newest batch of terms can be compared to something which adds up to $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Comparison_test. That's Oresme's proof from the Middle Ages!

Comment: A connection to other mathematics: taking the limit of both sides tells you that $\zeta(1)$ diverges. In fact, that's the most common proof of that fact that I've seen.

Answer (score 4):

**Base Case:** Let $n=1$. Then we have $1+1/2\geq 1+1/2$ and we are done.

**Inductive Step:** Assume the result holds for $n=k$. We wish to prove it for $n=k+1$. We know that $1+1/2+\cdots+1/2^k\geq 1+k/2$. Therefore we know that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{n}\geq 1+k/2+\sum_{n=2^k+1}^{2^{k+1}}\frac{1}{n}$$

Therefore to conclude we just need to show that the last summation is greater than $1/2$. A sum is always greater than it's smallest value times the number of terms, which in this case is $\frac{2^{k+1}-2^k}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{2}$ so we are done.

Notice that as mentioned in the comments, the same idea evoked at the end here can give a proof without the need for induction.

---

There should be another way to do it involving average values. Divide both sides by $2^{-n}$ and what you have on the LHS is the average value of $1/k$ on the set $\{1,2,\ldots,2^n\}$. The RHS is then $2^{-n}+n2^{-(n+1)}$ but I can't seem to see why that is less than the average value in question.