# Show that $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2^{n}-1}>\frac{n}{2}$

Tags: inequality

Show that $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{2^{n}-1}>\frac{n}{2}.$$

---

I used the fact that for all $k \ge 1:k <2^k$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n}-1}\frac{1}{k}>\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n}-1}\frac{1}{2^{k}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{2^{2^{n}-1}}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}\right)=1-\frac{1}{2^{2^{n}-1}}.$$

But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: You mean $1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + \dots + 1/(2^n -1)$?

Comment: Check this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209523/prove-by-induction-1-1-2-1-3-1-2n-%e2%89%a5-1-n-2

Comment: The latter series converges, so your comparison won't help any. Instead, try grouping terms in blocks of $2^i$ — $1+(1/2+1/3)+(1/4+1/5+1/6+1/7)+\ldots$ — and then bound each block from beneath.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove By Induction $1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/(2^n) ≥ 1 + n/2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209523/prove-by-induction-1-1-2-1-3-1-2n-%e2%89%a5-1-n-2)  It suffices to replace $n$ with $n-1$ in the dupe target to obtain a stronger result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ n\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $, denoting $ H_{n}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{1}{k}} $, we have : $$ H_{2n-1}-H_{n-1}=\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}{\frac{1}{k}}\geq\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}{\frac{1}{2n-1}}=\frac{n}{2n-1}> \frac{1}{2} $$

Thus, if $ k\in\mathbb{N} $, then : \begin{aligned}H_{2^{k+1}-1}-H_{2^{k}-1}&> \frac{1}{2}\\ \Longrightarrow\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(H_{2^{k+1}-1}-H_{2^{k}-1}\right)}&> \frac{n}{2}\\ \iff \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ H_{2^{n}-1}&>\frac{n}{2}\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $k\in\mathbb N$,

$$\frac{1}{2^k+1}+\frac{1}{2^k+1}+\frac{1}{2^k+2}+\cdots+ \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}>\frac{2^k}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\sum{k=1}^{2^n-1}\frac{1}{2^{k}}$ is an upper Riemann for the integral $\displaystyle\int_1^{2^n}\frac{\mathrm dx}x=\log(2^n)=n\log 2.$

Explain why $\:\log 2=\displaystyle\int_1^2\frac{\mathrm dx}x>\frac12$.